# mongod http interface not open

Tags: macos, mongodb

MBP Mid 2010 running OSX 10.11.6

I downloaded latest mongod binaries from https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community
Then I created the /data/db dir and ran `./mongod`
I see the DB port open at 27017, but there's no http interface open on port 28017 as expected.
Activity Monitor tells me the ports in use by mongod are:

```
*:27017
```

Is there another step needed to get the HTTP interface running on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the interface with the --rest option to mongod,then you may access it via a port that is 1000 more than the configured mongod port. 
The default port for the HTTP interface is 28017.

```
./mongod --rest
```